# In MQL5, how can I detect keypresses in MT5 running on a Mac

Tags: keyboard, mql5

When running MT5 on a PC, I can easily detect specific keys when pressed with this MQL5:

```
#import "user32.dll"
   int GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);
#import

// --- Windows Key Codes ---
#define VK_SHIFT    0x10    // SHIFT key
#define VK_CONTROL  0x11    // CTRL key
#define VK_ALT      0x12    // ALT key
#define VK_ESCAPE   0x1B    // ESC key

bool IsShift()
{
   return(IsKeyDown(VK_SHIFT));
}

bool IsCtrl()
{
   return(IsKeyDown(VK_CONTROL));
}

bool IsAlt()
{
   return(IsKeyDown(VK_ALT));
}

bool IsEscape()
{
   return(IsKeyDown(VK_ESCAPE));
}

bool IsKeyDown(int nVirtKey)
{
    return(GetKeyState(nVirtKey) > 1000);
}

// Run this crude diagnostic method every 1 second and hold down any key to see its key code
void GetKeyCodeOfKeyPressed()  // Display the key code and the key state
{
   for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++)
       if (IsKeyDown(k))
           Print("That's it! ",k," [",GetKeyState(k),"]");
}
```

The code above includes methods specifically trying to detect the PC keyboard modifier keys with individual checks, and the Escape key, as well as a more broad-based test to discover the key code for any pressed key in an attempt to see if it could discover the key codes on a Mac.

Running MT5 on a PC, the code above works exactly as one would expect. Running it on a Mac, the code does not detect any keypresses when a key is pressed. None. It's as if even GetKeyState is completely irrelevant on the Mac.

In MQL5 with MT5 running on a Mac, how can one detect specific keys pressed? If it is simpler to do this for a subset of keys, it is specifically the modifiers (or Mac equivalents) and Escape that are most relevant. The modifier keys will be used with mouse clicks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use those winapi functions

Look at for example

`TerminalInfoInteger(TERMINAL_KEYSTATE_CONTROL)`

https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/environment_state/terminalstatus

and

```
void OnChartEvent(const int id,const long& lparam,const double& dparam,const string& sparam) 
  {  
   if(id==CHARTEVENT_KEYDOWN) 
     { 
      short sym=TranslateKey((int)lparam);
     }
  }
```

https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/common/translatekey

Comment: Thanks, Dale. I'll give that a go. The docs say it may produce an error with keys like SHIFT. Given those modifier keys are precisely what I want to detect, is this an appropriate approach, or is there a more "guaranteed" way to detect just modifier keys, specifically as pressed for use with mouse-clicks, remembering this is on a Mac?

Comment: You will just have to play around with it and see if it works. I don't have any experience using metatrader on MacOS .